# Detect when the browser hits "refresh" in Python's BaseHTTPServer

Tags: python, basehttpserver

How can I detect when the client hits F5 / refresh? Are there any headers sent to the server to indicate this that I can grab? I'm doing some server-side caching and I'd like to automatically expire the cache when a refresh is detected. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ETags may be a more correct solution, but simply looking for the `Cache-Control` header is enough, since the browser will use it to indicate caches should not be used.

Chrome sends `Cache-Control: max-age=0`, but some other browsers send `Cache-Control: no-cache`. You may want to expire cache on any cache control header you don't recognize.

Or even:

```
if any(i.lower().startswith('cache-control:') for i in self.headers): #...
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd look at [ETags and conditional cache validation requests](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_ETag).

If the browser sends a `If-None-Match` header they had a cached copy and want to see if they can reuse it. Instead of sending a 304 Not Modified you instead clear your cache, produce a full 200 OK response and set a new ETag header.